# Quotient map in Munkres' book

Tags: general-topology

In Topology, the second edition by Munkres, in section 22, on page 137 he says the following:

"**Definiton.** Let Y and Y be topological spaces; let $p:X\rightarrow Y$ be a surjective map. The map $p$ is said to be a **quotient map** provided a subset $U$ of $Y$ is open in $Y$ if and only if $p^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$.

This condition is stronger than continuity; some mathematicians call it "strong continuity". An equivalent condition is to require that a subset $A$ of $Y$ be closed in $Y$ if and only if $p^{-1}(A)$ is closed in $X$. Equivalence of the two conditions follows from equation
\begin{align*}
 f^{-1}\left ( Y-B \right )=X-f^{-1}\left ( B \right )."
\end{align*}

I don't understand why the last equation is there? Is there any way to prove it?

Comment: Verify that each side is contained in the other. It is entirely trivial.

Comment: $x \in X-f^{-1}[B]$ iff $f(x) \notin B$ iff $f(x) \in Y-B$ iff $x \in f^{-1}[Y-B]$. Logic and definitions.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you want a proof of he equation

$$f^{-1}(Y-B) = X-f^{-1}(B),$$

i.e. that inverse mapping respects complements. This is a well-known fact from set theory and can easily be proven:

\begin{align*}
x \in f^{-1}(Y-B) \iff f(x) \in Y-B \iff x \in X-f^{-1}(B)
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

Write $(Y- B)$ as $(Y \cap B^c)$ and note that preimages commute with intersections